# Push notification in Blackberry debug portal Address field value

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-push

i give following error in blackberry push debug portal when i submit the push.
Blackberry debug-portal ---- > push Management  --->push
Address filed:
2002 The address specified was not in a recognized format or was not valid or unknown (i.e Not subscribed).

i give the push id rendmoly as 5.
i can not get which address is given in this field.

Answer (score 1):

This message means that the user you put in the "Adresses" field is not a registered user to your server => "(i.e Not subscribed)."
I guess you are using the Push Sample from Blackberry. You have to register an user from your blackberry device (not from a simulator !!) => Menu => Register. 
Then, from the debug portal, you will have to type the user you just created in the "Adresses" field

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/25167/PAP_response_status_codes_607260_11.jsp), error 2002 means "The specified PIN is not recognized."

In your XML, check the values you are passing in the `<address>` elements; they should be 8-character hex values. If you're using RIM's Java SDK for the server side, the `PushMessageControl` class takes `List<String>` for the device PINs (addresses).